# How to create different encoders for different users OR different user_roles?

Tags: security, symfony, encoding, roles

What is the best way to deal with situation than one wants to have different password encoders for different kind of users?

1) Should one create different user classes and than assign encoder for each,
for example,
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

2) Is it possible to assign different encoders for different USER_ROLES? How ?

thank you!

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/named_encoders.html

Comment: this also assigns encoder for the user class - case 1.  Is it possible to assign different encoders for different USER_ROLES? How ?

Comment: You will have to explain your question further.  Users have one or more roles.  The link shows how to test if a user has a particular role and adjust the password encoder accordingly.  User_roles don't have passwords nor do they login.  So I don't understand what "encoders for different USER_ROLES" mean.